# Getting Debug Information from Windows Phone Browser

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, hybrid-mobile-app

Is there any possibilities to get the details like "`loaded resources (test.html, test.js, test.css, test.png)`", "`console errors`" from the web page which is loaded in the Windows phone webbrowser control?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See WebBrowser.FileDownload & WebBrowser.ProgressChanged events?